# How I can customize query in view.popup in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am are using SugarCRM 6.7, I wanna customize the listview query in popup. I need a custom query when I open the Accounts popup in Cases module.

I was created a file in \custom\modules\Accounts\views\view.popup.php

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class CustomViewPopup extends ViewPopup{

    function CustomViewPopup(){

        parent::ViewPopup();
    }

}
```

But I need change the initial query, I tried to use $this->where = "whereCondition" equal in view.list.php but with no success.

How I can, change the initial query in view.popup? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a way to customize the sql queries inside the popup( view.popup.php ) in SugarCRM.

Create a file called view.popup.php in \custom\modules\< module >\views
with this:

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class CustomAccountsViewPopup extends ViewPopup{

    public function listViewProcess(){

        parent::listViewProcess();

        $this->params['custom_select'] = " CUSTOM SELEC";
        $this->params['custom_from'] = "CUSTOM FROM";
        $this->where .= " CUSTOM WHERE CONDITION";
    }

    function CustomAccountsViewPopup(){

        parent::ViewPopup();
    }

    function preDisplay(){
        parent::preDisplay();       

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this also possible in SuiteCRM?

Comment: @user1481792 I dont know SuiteCRM, I just try it on SugarCRM

Comment: Hey @ErasmoOliveira, I tried your solution, but in my scenario, `listViewProcess` never executes. Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: How can I get default query from which created on popupview?

Comment: muito bom mito!

Comment: Hello @ErasmoOliveira, were you able to add custom relate popup view? because I want to modify the clear function there and adding a readonly field for my pre-filtered data.

Comment: Hi, @ClintonCanarias, I dont work with sugar anymore for more than 8 years, sorry but I dont know how to help you

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira, its ok bro. thank you for your response. Even me never tried sugar yet. I am working with SuiteCRM