# SugarCRM Custom Query in popup list

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I need to customize the list of element shows in a popupview based on a relation.

I have these modules:

```
A->x (one-to-many)
A->y (one-to-many)
```

`x` have a related field to `y`

In detailview of `A`, a have the subpanels for `x` and `y` modules and I can create new `x` records and `y` records from quickcreateview.
In quickcreateview for `y`, I have to select by popupview an `x` element.

I have to customize this popupview for showing only `x` items that have relation with current (this detailview) A record (not all)

This solution is valid for me: [How I can customize query in view.popup in SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285938/how-i-can-customize-query-in-view-popup-in-sugarcrm)
but I need to create a query with a dynamic param with `A.id`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
In quickcreatedefs(in my example module 'y'), in related field to 'x' add:

```
'displayParams' => array(
        'initial_filter' => "&linea_id=".$_REQUEST['parent_id'],
         ),
```

$_REQUEST['parent_id'] is id of 'A' module.

And in popupdefa(in my example module 'x'), add:

```
'whereStatement'=> " id IN (SELECT presu_line9cc5aterial_idb from presu_lineastesmaterial_c where presu_line9fedupuesto_ida='".$_REQUEST['linea_id']."' and deleted=0)",
```