# In Sugar, how to customize popup search to display records depending on the selection of another relate field in Many-to-Many relationship scenario?

Tags: many-to-many, sugarcrm, popupwindow

I have two modules, consider A & B. In between them, there is many-to-many relationship. Now, there is another module, consider C. There is One-to-Many between A & C and B & C. Now while on editview of C module, both relate fields of module A & module B are present.

Now, after selecting any record from module A, while selecting records from module B, I want to show only those records which are related to the selected record of module A.

Now, I have came across these links, where they provided solution in the scenario of having One-to-Many relationship between these modules.

[How can I customize the popup search to display possibilities depending on the parent page?](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/18860)

[SugarCRM: relate field passing default values to pop-up select form](http://academe.co.uk/2013/03/sugarcrm-relate-field-passing-default-values-to-pop-up-select-form/)

Wherein "One-to-Many" scenario, we can achieve the same by adding following code to editviewdefs.php file of targeted module, like this:

```
'displayParams' => array(
    'initial_filter' => '&contact_name_advanced="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("contact_name").value)+"',
),
```

OR like this:

```
'displayParams' => array (   
    'initial_filter' => '&account_name={$fields.account_name.value}', 
),
```

But neither these posts mentioned any solution for "Many-to-Many" scenario nor I found any such post.

I came across another post:

[SugarCRM Custom Query in popup list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687238/sugarcrm-custom-query-in-popup-list)

where it suggested, along with above solution, to add few lines of code in popdefs.php file. But it is not wise option, as this popdefs.php file automatically generates by SugarCRM.

I came across few more posts:

[How to Override view.popup in sugar CE 6.5.18](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/22675)

[How I can customize query in view.popup in SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285938/how-i-can-customize-query-in-view-popup-in-sugarcrm)

where it suggested to customize the sql queries inside the popupview (view.popup.php) in SugarCRM. I tried that, but still I found no success. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: I face this problem and i solved it , but it is very difficult to share , try to use custom filter and break down the many-to-many relation into one to many relation .

Comment: Thank you @AmiteshKumar. I don't think I can break down that. It's been 5 days, that I am struggling to achieve this. I don't know, what do you mean "very dificult to share". But if possible, kindly help or give me some hint atleast.

Comment: tell me i am correct or not , in c module you want if A select according to A  , B data will filter if B select According to B A data will get filter , did i understand it ?

Comment: Yeah , @AmiteshKumar you are correct.