# SugarCRM: How to filter query in subpanel Select popup that is specific for one module only

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5. I have a Users subpanel from my custom module. When I click Select, I need to filter the list of users. The challenge is it will only filter when triggered from the custom module and should not from other module using the User popup.

Tried this solution [How I can customize query in view.popup in SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285938/how-i-can-customize-query-in-view-popup-in-sugarcrm) but it doesn't work on my end.

I manage to filter from User.php, adding the query filter in create_new_list_query, however it affects other module (it filters when it should not). I cannot figure out how to add condition for the custom module specific. It seems like it does not know what module that triggers the User popup.

Any possible solutions?
Your answers will be highly appreciated. Thank you!